# Logic to prepopulate select data in a for each Table

Tags: javascript

I have a table that is populated by a for each, so each row is one set of data pulling from a SQL table, call this tableA (or marketAccess table). Inside each row, one column holds a dropdown that is populated with a for each from a different SQL table (call it TableB) that holds company names. A second column shows the company code. I need this code to be pre-populated based on which Company name was selected in the first column. That data lives in tableB( or Carriers table). I am having issues figuring out the best way to prepopulate the company code.  I was able to get it to work by doing a drop down for each company code... but it looks a little janky. And if you select a new Company you have to refresh the page to get the company code to repopulate. Was wondering if there is a better way to populate the code, and to present it as text not a dropdown using Javascript to figure out which option was selected and then feed that information back to the column somehow...?

Any thoughts on the best way to tackle this would be super appreciated!

Here is the code for the table, with the code showing as a disabled dropdown.

```html
<table id="carrier-table" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Agency Code</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr th:each="access,stat : *{marketAccess}">
            <td>
                <select id="carrierDropDown" class="form-control" style="width:150px;" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].marketAccessCarrier}">
                    <th:block th:each="carrier : ${carriers}">
                        <option th:value="${carrier.id}" th:text="${carrier.carrierName}"></option>
                    </th:block>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" style="width:150px;" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].marketAccessCarrier.agencyCode}" disabled="true">
                    <th:block th:each="carrier : ${carriers}">
                        <option th:value="${carrier.id}" th:text="${carrier.agencyCode}"></option>
                    </th:block>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:125px;" id="username" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].username}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:125px;" id="password" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].password}"/></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Either you need to refresh the page or you need to have Javascript involved.  Static HTML can't rewrite a part of the DOM because you change a field on the screen.  Either way, I don't see this being a server side issue at all.  I don't see that this question has anything to do with Java, Spring Boot, or even Thymeleaf.

Comment: If a page refresh solves your problem, then the server side is doing all it can do.

Comment: @Steve,  my question is: is there a better way to populate this than a for each with Thymeleaf. Can I somehow do what I am trying to accomplish with inline Javascript?

Comment: Thymeleaf just writes HTML for you.  That's all it does.  It doesn't provide any runtime logic.   It just handles sending back the HTML you want it to when Spring responds to a request.  You need to think about your problem with Thymeleaf out of the picture and figure out how you want your app to act.  Then, once you've done that, you use Thymeleaf to generate the HTML you've decided that you need.  Thymeleaf has nothing to do with the logic of your app. -well, except that it puts the HTML and code together for you.  But it does that as a static operation that just produces a single HTML page.

Comment: This is a very basic web app design question.  I don't think it has anything to do with what technology you're using on the server side.  You could be talking about a Node.js server written in Javascript, and your question wouldn't change.

Comment: @Steve, thank you for the description on Thymeleaf, but do you have any suggestions on my question - how to prepopulate with inline Javascript? I would clearly use javascript to grab the value in the dropdown to find which was selected, but then I need to have the corresponding code populate in the html, how would I then display that information in the html?

Comment: I'm a back-end guy, so I'm not the person to ask.  I manage front-end people, but I stay blissfully ignorant.  I only came across this because of the tags you put on your question.  I would suggest that you repost your question with a different set of tags and a clearer question about the design of the logic and behavior of your app.  I hope you at least got some understanding from me of how Thymeleaf and the back end fit into this.  I'd be happy to help you with server-side questions, but I don't think that's where you should be focused yet.